# Is there any way to get the OS X JDK 7 as a zip file?

Tags: java, installation, java-7

So we got new iMacs at school but they're packing JDK 6. I have no admin rights (of course) but I'm guessing I could just have a folder and set JAVA_HOME to point there, since that's what I did on windows. The thing is I have no other mac to install it on and copy it from, and the IT team won't update it until the semester is over. So, is there any way to get the OS X JDK 7 as a zip file? I looked around and haven't found anything.

Maybe someone could upload it somewhere? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

idk what's up with the downvotes, but here's what I did and it works: http://dustinwtalk.com/java/2013/04/08/java-7-portable-for-osx-even-snow-leopard/